# How to detect hand gesture in live webcam using javascript?

Tags: html, javascript

I embedded live web cam to html page. Now i want to find hand gestures. How to do this using JavaScript, I don't have idea. I Googled lot but didn't get any good idea to complete this. So any one know about this? how to do this.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Accessing the webcam requires the HTML5 WebRTC API which is available in most modern browsers apart from Internet Explorer or iOS.

**Hand gesture detection** can be done in JavaScript using Haar Cascade Classifiers (ported from OpenCV) with [js-objectdetect](https://github.com/mtschirs/js-objectdetect/) or [HAAR.js](https://github.com/foo123/HAAR.js).

**Example** using js-objectdetect in JavaScript/HTML5: Open vs. closed hand detection (the "A" gesture of the american sign language alphabet)

[image: Open hand] [image: Closed hand or "A" gesture]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a JavaScript hand-tracking demo -- it relies on HTML5 features which are not yet enabled in all typical browsers, it doesn't work well at all here, and I don't believe it covers gestures, but it might be a start for you: http://code.google.com/p/js-handtracking/

Answer (score 2):

You need to have some motion detecting device (Camera) and you can use kinect to get the motion of different parts of the body. You will have to send data in browser telling about the body parts and position where you can manipulate the data according to your requirement

Here you can find how you can make it. [Motion detection and rendering](http://kinection.codeplex.com/)

More about kinect [General info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinect)

Comment: You need to say in your answer it only supports HTML5.. you imply it will work with JS.. which is untrue. Also this will only work in IE 9+ chrome,FF and Safari and most likely on Windows Only using .NET frameworks....

Comment: HTML5 is necessary to achieve this. The data collected by cam will be of two types on will be video (pictures) that are already rendering and other will be text data of body parts data (dimension: X, Y width, length etc). This data could be used for render on html5 canvas or simply shown in some div as a text.

Comment: and this solution is for *kinect only*? the OP did not mention any specific camera, but just a web camera in general.

Comment: Yes but i mentioned in my answer "motion detecting device (Camera)" without it detecting hand movement is very difficult. He might have to change the camera type to achieve what he wants

Answer (score 2):

While this is a really old question, theres some new opportunities to do handtracking using  fast neural networks and images from a webcam. And in Javascript. I'd recommend the [Handtrack.js](https://github.com/victordibia/handtrack.js) library which uses Tensorflow.js just for this purpose.

[image]

Simple usage example.

```
<!-- Load the handtrackjs model. -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handtrackjs/dist/handtrack.min.js"> </script>

<!-- Replace this with your image. Make sure CORS settings allow reading the image! -->
<img id="img" src="hand.jpg"/> 
<canvas id="canvas" class="border"></canvas>

<!-- Place your code in the script tag below. You can also use an external .js file -->
<script>
  // Notice there is no 'import' statement. 'handTrack' and 'tf' is
  // available on the index-page because of the script tag above.

  const img = document.getElementById('img'); 
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  // Load the model.
  handTrack.load().then(model => {
    // detect objects in the image.
    model.detect(img).then(predictions => {
      console.log('Predictions: ', predictions); 
    });
  });
</script>
```

[Demo](https://victordibia.github.io/handtrack.js/#/)
[Running codepen](https://codepen.io/victordibia/pen/RdWbEY)

Also see a similar neural network [implementation in python](https://github.com/victordibia/handtracking) -

Disclaimer .. I maintain both projects.

Comment: This sounds very interesting. We have a public kiosk system (webcam built in every device), and if we could get thumb/fingerpoint-up/down (to supplement scroll arrows), some gesture to click and 1-2 more, we'd have a great thing, especially in Corona-frightened days...